# How to trigger a jenkins build in background while propagating error with the pipeline plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I am experimenting with the jenkins pipeline scripting.

I have a job which will call other build for deploying stuff.
This is my pipeline script

```
node {
   stage 'retrieve deploy conf'
   echo 'contacting deploy conf service'
   def dbs = ['db1', 'db2', 'db3']
   for (db in dbs){
    stage 'deploy db ' + db
    echo 'deploy db ' + db
    build job: 'deploy db pipeline', wait: false, parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'db', value: db]]

   }
   def jbossApps = ['example-ear1', 'example-ear2']
   for (app in jbossApps){
    stage 'deploy jboss app ' + app
    echo 'deploy jboss app' + app
    build job: 'deploy app pipeline', wait: false
   }
}
```

For each value in a loop, i want to have different stages (for visibility).
I have now set the wait param on the build call to false, but this results that no error are propagated.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `parallel` step (calling one `build` per branch) and remove `wait: false`, instead of the for loop.

Use `failFast: true` in `parallel` step to stop the build as soon as the first branch fails.